# p:dialog visible="true" doesn't show when used in "page that contains other elements"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, facelets, visible

I am having a problem with a `<p:dialog>`

I am using

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{prijemnicaBean.proveriProdajneObjekte}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

to set a showDialog boolean depending on a condition in the method.

```
<p:outputPanel id="dialogId">
<p:dialog header="Greska" visible="#{prijemnicaBean.showDialog}" closable="false">
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{prijemnicaBean.disableShowDialog()}" update=":dialogId"/>
    ...
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton action="#{prijemnicaBean.vratiUnos}" value="Ok"/>
    </h:form> 
</p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I have this dialog on my page and when I only have the dialog and metadata tag in my body section, everything works just fine, but when I insert it into my page that contains other elements, the dialog doesn't show up, even though showDialog = true.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks like this is question # 8,000,000. Congratulations :)

Comment: *"but when I insert it into my page that contains other elements"* - You'd in your question better post actual non-working code instead of working code. It's hard to see where you made the mistake. Although there are multiple probable causes for this the most commonly one is that you've erroneously declared `<f:metadata>` outside `<ui:define>`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for hints as to creating a proper snippet.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the <f:metadata> anywhere in my code. The whole code is quite long, but even if I add a form after the dialog tag, with any other element in it, the dialog won't show.

Comment: aren't u using show() method on dialog widgetwar to show the dialog? from where are u calling that?

Comment: no, I am using the "visible" option of the dialog